# JAVA/JAVAC: label & break exact semantic

Tags: java

Let consider some examples on label and break statements in Java and try to compile its by OpenJDK (v18) javac. The main goal is the getting exact semantics of labels and branches (and continues).

Version1.

```
public class L {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        System.out.println( "Start\n");
Label1:
Label2:
        break Label1;
        //break Label2;
        System.out.println( "Finish\n");
    }
}
```

Compile and disassembly.

```
$ javac L.java && echo $?
0
$ javap -c L
    ...
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #13                 // String Start\n
       5: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: ldc           #21                 // String Finish\n
      13: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      16: return
}
```

There is no any goto instructions in bytecode. (Possibly it is a result of the optimization during a bytecode generation. The AST of this example have a JCLabeledStatement and a JCBreak tree nodes.) Change example in two ways.

Version2.

```
        //break Label1;
        break Label2;
```

It is still like Version1.

Version3.

```
        break Label1;
        break Label2;
...
$ javac L.java
L.java:8: error: undefined label: Label2
        break Label2;
        ^
1 error
```

Is Version3 an incorrect? When javac compiles Version1 and Version2 is it feature? Or the examples are both incorrect, but OpenJDK's javac doesn't catch syntax errors according to JAVA Language Standard.

POSSIBLE EXPLANATION.

```
Label1:
Label2:
    break Label1;
```

means

```
Label1: {
    Label2: {
        break Label1;
    }
}
```

and Version3 means

```
Label1: {
    Label2: {
        break Label1;
    }
}
break Label2;
```

Of course `break Label2` tryies to use Label2 outside of its scope.
(Numerous tutorials about `break` with label concentrate on for/while.)

Comment: Did you read [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now it seems I understand my initial mistake in the meaning of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's look how the statements are parsed. The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) of a labeled statement is:

```
LabeledStatement:
    Identifier : Statement
LabeledStatementNoShortIf:
    Identifier : StatementNoShortIf
```

A labeled statement has a label and contains inner statement.

So in the first two cases,

```
Label1:
Label2:
break Label2;
```

is parsed as a single labeled statement, with the label `Label1` as the label, and another labeled statement as its contained statement. The contained labelled statement has `Label2` as the label, and a break statement as *its* contained statement.

The AST looks a bit like this:

```
LabeledStatement
    Identifier ('Label1')
    ':'
    LabeledStatement
        Identifier ('Label2')
        ':'
        BreakStatement
```

In the third case,

```
Label1:
Label2:
break Label1;
break Label2;
```

is parsed as two statements. The first statement has the same structure as above, and the second statement is a break statement.

The spec also says:

> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately contained Statement.

This explains why the third statement does not compile. The scope of the `Label2` label does not include the second statement (`break Label2;`) in the third case. It only includes statement that is immediately following the label. In the first two cases, the labels are all in scope, because you are using them in the contained statement.

The semantics of a break statement is specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15).

> A break statement with label `Identifier` attempts to transfer control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same Identifier as its label; this enclosing statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the break target need not be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement.

In the first two cases, the `break` statement transfers control itself, and immediately causes itself to complete normally. This is basically a no-op, and so does not produce any bytecode.

Comment: Just in case I would like to clarify: Are break/return/continue additionally unlock all monitors for leaving synchronization-blocks and "remove" all exception landingpads for leaving try-blocks?

Comment: @Павел It does unlock the monitor if you leave a `synchronised` block with a `break`. I am not sure what you mean by "exception landingpads". You mean `catch` blocks? If you leave a `try` block with a `break`, it will not go to any `catch` blocks, but the `finally` block (if any) will still run.

Comment: My use of terms is inaccurate, I'm new in Java. So ```L1: synchronised (foo) { break L1; }``` will kept ```foo``` is locked? And There is no way to unlock ```foo``` after ```break L1```, isn't it?

Comment: @Павел No, you misunderstand. That will not keep `foo` locked.

Comment: @Павел You can test this simply by running that code *two times*, and see if it deadlocks :)

Comment: Ok! If I am right, monitors are the internal realization in Java Machine of ```synchronised``` concept (or in bytecode?).  So "monitors" will be "unlocked" :)?

Comment: @Павел Yes, the internal monitor of `foo` will be unlocked. Comments are not for extended discussions. If you are still confused. Please post a new question about how `break` works `synchronized`, and include a [mcve].